# Sharepoint 2007 - SQL Server Access Error

Tags: web-part

I have developed a web part and trying to access the SQL Server 2008 from the button click Event in the web part and I get the following error.

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed
```

I have tried this post but not helped me. I want to find out what is cause for this error.

[This Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/1505d7e6-59dc-4997-b707-9e9736a1f978/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows authentication on SQL server most likely you have double-hop issue:

[Sharepoint Single Sign-On, Impersonation and the Double-Hop Problem](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/sharepoint-single-sign-on-impersonation-and-the-double-hop-problem/)

Simplified: user credentials are 'lost' when you reach SQL server and SQL denies your request.

Simplest solution for this is to put your SQL server in mixed mode and use SQL Server Authentication to allow access from your webpart.